# Add users to Asp.Net MVC 5 standard user management from external app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to make a simple web service for internal company use which will use standard authentication but without open registration. All users will be added manually from external application.

I connected my Asp.Net application to SQL database and in **`AspNetUsers`** table I can see users but as far as I understand I can't add users directly since password is hashed and, salted(?) I guess, so I need to somehow generate this hash. Plus there is something called **`SecurityStamp`** which I guess I need to generate somehow as well.

So is there a way to add users of Asp.Net MVC 5 app directly to database or somehow else from external tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try [Thinktecture's IdentityManager](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) project? It's created for this purpose. Creater [Brock Allen](http://brockallen.com/) also shot some videos in order to use it on different authorization systems. Have a look at these videos.

- [Setting up ASP.NET Identity](https://vimeo.com/125426951)
- [Security and IdentityManager](https://vimeo.com/125427106)